# Importing Leaflet in Angular 16 Stackblitz?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet, stackblitz

Trying to import `leaflet` in this Angular 16 Stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-kw6bmy?file=src%2Fmain.ts

It has both `@types/leaflet` and `leaflet` packages installed, however it produces the error.

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'leaflet'. '/turbo_modules/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet-src.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/leaflet` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'leaflet';`
```

Thoughts?