# Configuring ngx-leaflet to use the leafletLayers option?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet, ngx-leaflet

Trying to get the `[leafletLayers]` option to work with [ngx-leaflet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet).

[I created a demo](https://github.com/fireflysemantics/leaflet) of this on Github, [because Stackblitz is currently not loading leaflet correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76614477/importing-leaflet-in-angular-16-stackblitz).

The demo works fine with the geo json data being added via the leaflet API after the `mapReady` call is made.

```
  private createGeoJsonLayer(map: L.Map): L.GeoJSON<any> {
    const layers: L.GeoJSON<any> = L.geoJSON(this.geoJsonData, {
      style: {
        weight: 2,
        color: 'orange',
        opacity: 0.8,
        fillColor: 'red',
        fillOpacity: 0.6,
      },
      onEachFeature: (feature, layer) => {
        this.onEachFeature(feature, layer);
      },
    });
    //==============================
    // Add layers to map
    //==============================
    layers.addTo(map);

    return layers;
  }
```

However `layers.addTo(map)` is commented out, the geo json layer no longer renders.

I was expecting it to render anyways since it is assigned in the template like this:

```
<div
leaflet
style="height: 300px;"
leaflet
[leafletLayers]="geoJsonLayers"
[leafletOptions]="leafletOptions"
(leafletMapReady)="mapReady($event)"
></div>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: https://github.com/bluehalo/ngx-leaflet/issues/360

Answer (score 0):

OK - Figured it out.  The result of the call to `L.geoJSON` has to be wrapped in an array.  So instead of returning `L.geoJSON` we have to return `[L.geoJSON]`.

Here's a sample implementation:

```
  private createGeoJsonLayer(): [L.GeoJSON<any>] {
    const layers: L.GeoJSON<any> = L.geoJSON(this.geoJsonData, {
      style: {
        weight: 2,
        color: 'orange',
        opacity: 0.8,
        fillColor: 'red',
        fillOpacity: 0.6,
      },
      onEachFeature: (feature, layer) => {
        this.onEachFeature(feature, layer);
      },
    });
    return [layers];
  }
```

Note that the `resetHightlight` method needs access to the result, so the implementation should access the first item in array like this:

```
  private resetHighlight(featureLayer:any) {
    if (featureLayer) {
      this.geoJsonLayers[0].resetStyle(featureLayer);
    }
  }
```